# Intergrating AspDotNetStorefront with a custom ASP.net application

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I would like to integrate AspDotNetStorefront with a custom ASP.net application. Any ideas on how to go about it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you as you start to explore your strategy is to get aquainted with how the whole system works.  You will notice that all of your normal Global.aspx Application_Start, Begin_Request methods are located in the ASPDNSF.Core assembly.  You will see them somewhere are line 12000 (ish).  These are fired as usual just like Global.aspx

```
    public static void Custom_SessionEnd_Logic(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // put any custom session end logic you need here...
        // do not change this routine unless you know exactly what you are doing
    }
    public static void Custom_Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // put any custom application error logic you need here...
        // do not change this routine unless you know exactly what you are doing
    }
    public static void Custom_Application_EndRequest_Logic(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // put any custom application end request logic you need here...
        // do not change this routine unless you know exactly what you are doing
    }
```

Following the flow of execution will bring you to a non-traditional way of programming asp.net websites.  ASPDOTNETStorefront does not incorporate a very good separation of concerns, so often times you will see style code directly injected into the ASPDNSF.controls.dll assembly. This can be very frustrating if your business logic requirements require features not supported out of box.  But like anything in .NET its all possible.

I propose that you create a customization folder inside the web solution and create your custom user control from there and deploy them around the site as needed.  Try as best to not modify too much of the source code implemented by the ASPDNSF team because many of the application behavior is controlled by the supporting dlls and the administration interface relies heavily on user app-settings set in the backend, as opposed to getting custom arguments from Web.config.

I have been working with ASPDNSF since 2009 and I can tell you that it takes time to migrate a currently successful platform into the website but it is doable.  The XML Templates are powerful but a little dated.

One important note:  As stated before, try not to mess around modifying the stored procedures, logic and queries packed into the solution as you can find yourself going past the point of no return when seeking to update the system.  This happened in my case and I learned my lesson.  I have been forced with taking what ASPDNSF team has done and almost completely modifying the original code base of ML9 multi-store.

Good Luck to you:)